# What is the best way to find the nearest scatter plot point (circle) relative to a given coordinate set?

Tags: d3.js, geometry, nearest-neighbor

Let's say I have 16 circles in an 2 x 8 grid:

```
svg = d3.select(body).append('svg').attr('height,h).attr('width',w);

svg.selectAll('.centroids')
      .data(d3.range(0,16))
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class','centroids')
      .attr('r','5')
      .attr('cx', function(d,i) { return i * 10; })
      .attr('cy', function(d,i) {
        if (i > 7) return 20;
        return 10;
      });
```

Given a random coordinate in that space, how do I determine the nearest `.centroid` point?

One way in N time is of course to loop through all the points, measuring the hypotenuse to the difference in `x` and `y` coordinates, choosing the smallest value.

I'd like to find a better way though. Does anyone know an optimized way?

Comment: Are the coordinates fixed according to your code, or do you want a more general solution for *any* possible set of positions?

Comment: The coordinate will be fixed to a grid (not necessarily the same as above). A general solution is ideal.

Comment: Why not using voronoi? Have a look at this example: http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/07/voronoi.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimization will depend on your exact settings:

- if you have a few nodes (16 as in your example), in random positions, then your method is probably optimal (just compute the square of the hypotenuse, which gains a few square root operations).
- if you have  many nodes in random positions, you'll want to start considering `quadtrees` to manage your nodes. The overhead is not negligible, so don't bother about it until you have hundreds or thousands or nodes. On the plus side, `d3`has it all coded for you.
- for a grid:

  ```
  var startx=0;
  var offsetx=10;
  var cols=8;
  var starty=10;
  var offsety=10;
  var rows=2; 
  var xi=d3.median([0,cols-1, Math.round((x-startx)/stepx)])
  var yi=d3.median([0,rows-1, Math.round((y-starty)/stepy)])
  var i=xi + yi*cols
  ```

  this is constant time, adjust the (many) constants according to your dimensions.

  A bit of details: `(x-startx)/stepx` allows to scale the coordinates so that the first dot is at 0, the next at 1, etc. `Math.round` gives the nearest integer, `d3.median` pushes the result between `0` and `cols-1` (check out each case, by all mean it's nicer than nested ifs).... overall this gives the index of the nearest column, then you do the same for the rows, and there you are!

Comment: Great answer. +1 for the [quadree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214) approach, but totally agree that it's not necessarily the most optimal solution for this problem, given the number of points and the fact that they're gridded